# Making asynchronous requests faster

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a code that checks a file of URLs, there could be potentially 1M+. What I'm struggling with is that even processing 5000 URLs takes around 1 hour and 30 minutes.

Is there a way the requests can be made even more efficient?

Sample code:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

URLS = [
   ...
]

async def get_response(session, url):
        try:
            async with session.get(url, ssl=False) as r:
                if r.status == 200:
                    return r
                return 
        except aiohttp.ClientError:
            return
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            return
        except ValueError:
            return
            

async def check_urls_async(urls):
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=1000)
    timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=None, sock_connect=5, sock_read=5)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector, trust_env=True, timeout=timeout) as session:

        tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(get_response(session, url)) for url in urls]
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   asyncio.run(check_urls_async(URLS))
```

**EDIT #1**: I ran a benchmark test similar to one on [this site](https://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2017/06/12/making-100-million-requests-with-python-aiohttp/) and 5000 requests finished in 3.5 seconds. So it seems hardware is not the issue and might be a network issue instead.

Here is the list of URLs that take me 1 hour and 30 mins to process:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opendns/public-domain-lists/master/opendns-random-domains.txt

Comment: Are you sure that the slowness is not caused by: 1. 100% CPU use of your Python process? 2. saturated network link? To rule out the network slowness, all URLS should be on http://127.0.0.1/...

Comment: Have you compared the speed of your Python script with curl + [parallel](https://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel)? If they are of the same speed, then it's not a Python asyncio problem. Have you compared the speed of your Python script with running 1000 Python processes in parallel (try *import multiprocessing*), downloading a web page each (try *import requests*)?

Comment: If I feed your code a list of 5000 URLs, it completes in about 12 seconds.

Comment: So the CPU is stable at 4% and I tried to benchmark it on a localhost server, which resulted in a time of 3.5 seconds with 5000 URLs @pts

Comment: Based on more info (127.0.0.1) in the comment, your Python code is correct, and the slow execution is caused by a slow network connection.

Comment: @Daniel I would also replace `ensure_future` with `create_task` which is the preferred method of creating tasks in asyncio. See the documentation also: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html *Important See also the create_task() function which is the preferred way for creating new Tasks.*